# If a Google dynamic map is hidden on page does it count as a map load?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a websites where a google static map is shown on page load.

If the user then clicks on the map then the static map is hidden and a div containing the dynamic map is shown in its place.  This is done using jQuery.

I can see from the [google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload) it says:

> A single map load is charged when any of the following occur:
>   A web page or application displays a map using the Maps JavaScript API.

But what I'm not clear on is that if the map is not visible on page load, does this counts as a map 'display' or not?

I have done some cursory testing by monitoring quota usage of the Maps Javascript API through the Google Cloud Platform as I reload a test page.

From this testing I think that it doesn't count as a page display if the dynamic map is hidden, but as I'm not able to isolate the page I'm testing from in the Cloud Platform console it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: It's called a "map load" not a "map display". Are you **loading** the API on page load? If yes, then it will be counted as a map load. Whether your map is displayed or not is not taken into account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but about understanding the terms of use or documentation of a third-party service.

Comment: The docs do say that a 'map load' is counted when the map is 'displayed'.  It's the 'display' that is ambiguously worded.

Here's the [network trace](http://i.damselflycreative.com/2019/05/chrome_2019-05-07_13-55-38.png) from initial page load

And [this is the network trace](http://i.damselflycreative.com/2019/05/chrome_2019-05-07_14-00-54.png) for when the dynamic map is shown

Comment: It's about the behaviour of interacting with an API, which is surely programming related?

Comment: I agree it is ambiguous. Whether your map is DISPLAYED or not (CSS rules), Google doesn't know. I believe the map load is counted once you have created the map instance (`new google.maps.Map()`). This should be fairly easy to test.

Comment: I would expect an API "map load" to be a load of the javascript API.  Are you dynamically loading the API only when needed (when you display your dynamic map)?  Although reading the text, it might very well be the instantiation of the map instance as MrUpsidown indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find what is charged as a map load in the Usage and Billing documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing#dynamic-maps

The `SKU: Dynamic Maps` corresponds to map loads and Google gives the following explanation

> A web page or application that displays a map using the Maps JavaScript API. A **map is created with the google.maps.Map()** class.

That means each time when you call `new google.maps.Map(options)` in your JavaScript code you will incur a map load that will be charged.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.